# Calculating the difference between multi-line strings PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to store some data locally in a database.

Now every time I change my articles, I want to know how many lines got added, and how many got deleted?

Kind of like: [image]

Is there an easy where were I compare the `$old_string` vs `$new_string`, and work out the difference in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `xdiff_string_diff` with setting `$context` to 0 and check the output. Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php)